# Infer constructor type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

Is it possible to infer the constructor type of a class in TypeScript?
I tried this but it seems not to work:

```
type Constructor<K> = K extends { new: infer T } ? T : any;
```

Comment: What about: `type Constructor<K> = K extends { new: () => infer T } ? T : any;`

Comment: `class Foo {}`,  `type CtorOfFoo = typeof Foo`

Comment: Can you edit this to show a [mcve] of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

There is already a predefined conditional type that allows you to extract the instance type from a class type, called `InstanceType`

```
class A { private x: any}

type AInstance = InstanceType<typeof A> // same as A
```

The definition of this type is:

```
type InstanceType<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

Comment: Looks interesting but unfortunately, I need it the other way around.

Comment: @MarkusMauch not clear what you mean, you need to get the class type based on the instance type ? Don't think that information is accessible from the instance type

Comment: Yeah, it's a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) that a class instance doesn't have a strongly-typed `constructor` property.  So unless you just want to get `Function`, you're probably stuck with `new (...args: any) => T` unless you manually strengthen the `constructor` property on all the classes you care about.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to infer it, can you refer to class types by their constructor functions like this?

```js
type Constructor<K> = { new(): K };

const x: Constructor<String> = String; 

const s = new x();
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, doing `typeof ClassA` is what you need. But you can also create a util type to manually infer the constructor type

```
type Constructor<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = T extends new (...args: infer A) => infer R ? new (...args: A) => R : neverÏ
```